# HTML email image inverts on link click Outlook 07/10/13

Tags: html, css, email, hyperlink, outlook

I'm having an issue on a HTML email in Word rendered Outlooks (2007, 2010, 2013) where I click an image link, and when the mouse is clicked, the image inverts... Here is the code below...

```
<td align="left" width="360" valign="top" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse;" class="hide">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="test.jpg" width="360" height="528" alt="alt tag" style="display:block;" class="img_mob centertable" border="0" align="left">
    </a>
</td>
```

Here is a comparison on the image clicked/not clicked...

[image: image not clicked]
[image: imiage clicked]

I have tried putting a `text-decoration: none` on the link. All the links are styled inline as well. This is the only image that it is having this issue on the email, so tried re-saving the image with no luck.

The image is saved as a JPEG and SRGB from a Photoshop PSD.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happened when you remove the `<a>` tag? Image appears normal?

Comment: @KheemaPandey that's correct yes, so something is telling me it is to do with the link...

Comment: and what CSS you are using for `a` tag? can you use a PNG format image? may be help you.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I have tried this, hasn't worked. There is no CSS attached to the a tag

Comment: why don't you use a fresh template provided by `Email Acid` have a look at this link. http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/emailology_a_free_responsive_email_template_using_media_queries_-_part_i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a look at your code, it looks like this issue was caused by the "align" attribute on your image. Removing this should fix it. You might want to add an align to the TD instead and give the image an inline CSS float style.